# TFS WEbsite Build arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

What is the proper format of MSBuild arguments on TFS website queue build popup? I can't find any documentation and no matter what I pass in I always get this error

```
Exception Message: The build controller cannot deserialize the process parameters of the build. Make sure the process parameters are compatible with the assemblies on the build machine. Details: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. (type Exception)
    Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.AddParameterValues(IDictionary`2 parameters, String processParameters)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)

    Inner Exception Details:

    Exception Message: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. (type XmlException)
    Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
       at System.Xaml.XmlCompatibilityReader.Read()
       at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlScanner.DoXmlRead()
       at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlScanner.Read()
       at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<Parse>d__0.MoveNext()
       at MS.Internal.Xaml.NodeStreamSorter.StartNewNodeStreamWithSettingsPreamble()
       at MS.Internal.Xaml.NodeStreamSorter..ctor(XamlParserContext context, XamlPullParser parser, XamlXmlReaderSettings settings, Dictionary`2 xmlnsDictionary)
       at System.Xaml.XamlXmlReader.Initialize(XmlReader givenXmlReader, XamlSchemaContext schemaContext, XamlXmlReaderSettings settings)
       at System.Xaml.XamlServices.Load(XmlReader xmlReader)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(String parameterValues)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.AddParameterValues(IDictionary`2 parameters, String processParameters)
```

I'm using the following template
[XML Build Template](http://snipt.org/Vtfe2/)
How do you troubleshot this ? Is there a way to somehow step through the build as it's happening ?

Comment: Does the build works fine when you don't pass any parameters? From the error, it seem like a build template issue. Which build template are you using?

Comment: Yes it does work without issues if I don't pass in any arguments. I'm using customized build template. I'm not even sure where to begin in troubleshooting the build template. Is there a plain vanilla one that I could try to see if the issue is still there ?

Comment: Yes, please use the DefaultTemplate or share the build template here so we can help. thanks.

Comment: I've added my current template. Could you take a look at it ?

Comment: I've ran it with the default template and same thing happens. Exactly same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug going through the web UI for TFS2012.  I had the same problem, and have had to do it from within visual studio.

A reference link here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/feb004ca-d2da-48f1-a052-74ddd15beaf4/setting-msbuildarguments-in-queue-new-build-dialog-of-tfs-web-interface-dialog-fails?forum=tfsgeneral

A not-so-useful recommendation was to upgrade to TFS2013 (I can't confirm if it works).